# Why this function doesn't return the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

This class has a function `name`, which should return the dog's name (`"Boby"` in following the example).

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(EstePerro, Nombre=None, Peso=None):
        EstePerro._Name = Nombre 
        EstePerro._Weight = Peso
    def name(EstePerro):
        "Returns dog name"
        return EstePerro._Name

pet = Dog("Boby",45)
print(pet.name)
```

But instead it returns this:

```
<bound method Dog.name of <__main__.Dog object at 0x0000000002DD4748>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call it. pet.name()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `pet.name` **is your method**
- `pet.name()` **is a call** to your method

So here, you need to add parenthesis to call your `name` method:

```
>>> pet = Dog("Boby", 45)
>>> print(pet.name()) # Parentheses after pet.name
Boby
```

Comment: That's it. I need to wait 11 minutes to mark it as answer. Any explanation on how the printed error explains it?

Comment: No problem :) I added the explanation.

Comment: I mean, that I do not understand "bound method Dog.name of..". I'm not sure if it is an error, or is actually what is printed by the instruction print(pet.name)

Comment: It is not an error. That's just what happens when you `print` a method.